# How to change Python cache path

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10

When I install and run natural language processing modules like `nlp` or `Spacy` they often download large machine learning modules into `C:\Users\User\.cache` directories or similar directories on the `C:\` drive in Windows. Since my `C:` drive is a solid state drive with limited space I keep on running out of space on it. I also tried to change my Windows 10 user directory to be on my `D:` drive but most programs just seem to ignore the Windows user directory change. I could not find any way to change these directories, does anyone know how I can do this?